# System time is drifting behind, how to keep it updated

Tags: time, clock

I've inherited a machine running ubuntu 12.04. The system clock has drifted and is now behind actual time by 6 minutes.

In the "Date and Time" panel, I see that "Network Time" is on. Timezone is correct.

I'm not sure where the network time is coming from, and how to get it back in sync with the rest of the world.

What's the right way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Use the command "sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com" and see what happens.

Comment: Do you have the ntp package installed?  That might fix things.

Comment: What would the result of "sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com" be? I'm not sure if ntp is even installed. I don't want the clock to change immediately - would there be a way to drift the clock back to the correct time using ntp?

Comment: By default, the ntp daemon adjusts the clock in one go. However, if you start the daemon with `ntpd -x`, adjustments will be small and it will take a while for your clock to be in sync. See the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ntpd).